Checkout Page Fails to Load After Magento 2.4.7-p3 Upgrade with CSP Enabled
I recently upgraded my Magento store to version 2.4.7-p3 and encountered an issue where the checkout page fails to load. I am using Mageplaza's One Step Checkout extension.
After some investigation, I found that the problem is related to Content Security Policy (CSP) restrictions. However, I want to keep CSP enabled for enhanced security and ensure the checkout page functions correctly.
Here are the console errors I’m seeing:
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Mageplaza_Osc/3columns" template requested by "checkout".
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/shipping" component.
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/form/element/region" component.
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Mageplaza_Osc/container/authentication" template requested by "checkout.authentication".

Here are the steps I've tried so far:

Checked browser console logs for CSP violations.

Verified that CSP rules in my configuration are in place for other parts of the store.


Despite this, the checkout page still doesn't load properly.
Questions:

How can I identify the exact CSP directives that are blocking
resources on the checkout page?
What would be the best way to configure or extend CSP policies
specifically for Mageplaza's One Step Checkout without compromising
overall security?

Any guidance or best practices for handling CSP with third-party extensions like Mageplaza's One Step Checkout would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

This is not related to CSP. Your custom module (Mageplaza_Osc) is not compatible with the latest Magento.

For a temporary fix to address the checkout page issue, you can create a config.xml file in your custom module under the etc folder and add the following code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
          <mode>
           <storefront_checkout_index_index>
           <report_only>1</report_only>
          </storefront_checkout_index_index>
       </mode>
    </csp>
 </default>
</config>

After adding this code, your checkout page should work properly, and the CSP mode will be set to "report-only.
For a permanent solution, since CSP is enabled by default in Magento 2.4.7, review and fix any inline scripts used on the checkout page, as inline scripts are deprecated. you can make a incline script in this way
<?php $scriptString = <<<script
        require(['jquery'],function($){
 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
         console.log("Hello checkout");
    });
}); 
script;
   ?>
  <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?> 

Once all issues with inline scripts on the checkout page are resolved, the checkout page will work automatically with CSP enabled by default. At that point, you can safely remove the temporary solution.
